# How to display localized exception messages in Xamarin Forms android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, localization

I have developed an android app using Xamarin Forms. There is a call to `httpClient.GetAsync` method to get response from a server. If I give an invalid server name, then the Exception in `catch` returns **The operation was canceled.**

`System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.`

I changed mobile language to French, Spanish locales but always the error message is in English.
Is there a way to get error message translated based on mobile device's active locale ?

Below is the code snippet:

```
try
 {
     using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
     {
         httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
         httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(myServerAddress);
     }
    return AppResourceString.Success;
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     return ex.Message;
 }
```

Comment: Don't want to start a war on religions here, but imo (yes, opinion based...) exception messages should stay in english, whereas user messages (whooops, something went wrong, please retry) can be localized. What i mean: log your `ex.Message` but show your user a user friendly error. E.g.: `ShowError("OPERATION_CANCELED", CurrentLanguage)` - simplified, but you get the point.

Comment: Another thing to add. If you use third party packages, that implent their own exceptions, you can not be sure, that they localized those messages. And i would not rely on the assumption, that all .NET exceptions are localized too.

Comment: What are your resx files ?

Comment: @Umar3x my resx files have known strings translated for multiple languages. But I was expecting .Net framework standard exceptions does support localization by default.

Comment: Alright ... then juste create your own type of exception that derives from exception. Add a new property UserMessage and put your localized message there. If you don't know how to achieve it, just look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions